# Connects a collection viewer firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a table with table material i was watching a tutorial about connecting material table to firebase but i got a error that i didn't understand

The error message upon connect:

```
Property 'connect' in type 'chauffeurDataSource' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'DataSource<any>'.
  Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer) => Observable<any[] | readonly any[]>'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[] | readonly any[]>'.
```

This is my code, in `landing.componnet.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { CollectionViewer, DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections'
import {AngularFirestore} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {chauffeurs} from '../../shared/models/chauffeur'

import { chauffeurService } from "src/app/shared/service/ChaufffeurService";
import { Observable } from "rxjs-compat";
@Component({
 selector: "app-landing",
 templateUrl: "./landing.component.html",
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {
 displayedColumns = ['nometprenom', 'Active', 'Nombre de lot', 'Montant total du lot', 'Nombre de colies livrée','Sommes livrées','Sommes livrée','Somme dues'];
 dataSource =new chauffeurDataSource(this.chauffeur.getchauffeur())
 constructor(private chauffeur:chauffeurService) {}


 

 ngOnInit(): void {}


}

export class chauffeurDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
 
  connect() {
    return this.chauffeur.getchauffeur();

 }
  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
  constructor(private chauffeur: chauffeurService){
   super()
  }
 
  
}
```

Comment: I think that this [Github link](https://github.com/irossimoline/angular4-material-table/issues/37) could help you with this issue.

Comment: can you share the link of the tutorial that you are following